# how to split an integer array that the server recieve from the client

Tags: java, arrays

The client passes an array and has the `&` sign in it.

I want the server to split the integer before and after & into two columns, but I don't know how as i am using integers not strings and i don't know how to cast it with ObjectInputstream.

**Server side:**

```
package server;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Server {     
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            ServerSocket srvr = new ServerSocket(6013);
            Socket skt = srvr.accept();
            System.out.print("Server has connected!\n");


            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(skt.getInputStream());
            int[] o = (int[])in.readObject();

            System.out.println("Received this object on the server:  
                    "+Arrays.toString(o) +",");
                    skt.close();
                    srvr.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

**Client side:**

```
package client; 
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*; 
import array.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
            Socket sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 6013);
            int[] process;
            process = new int[]{4,5&6,6,7};
            //      int[] arrival;
            //    arrival = new int[]{4,5,6,7};
            //   int[] burst;
            //   burst = new int[]{4,5,6,7};

            ObjectOutputStream out = new    
                    ObjectOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
            out.writeObject(process);


        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {}
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please show your input and expected output? you have `{4,5&6,6,7}` what you need to do with it? `{4,5,6,6,7}`?

Comment: `(int) (5&6) == 0101 & 0110 == 4`, this will be converted to 4 and send as `4`not `5&6`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are newcomer, I will try to answer in detail.

First of all your array is an array of integer. You would expect that the `&` sign in the array is an actual sign in your array but you are wrong. The array is ONLY composed of integer.

So what happens to 5&6 ?
jhamon already said that 5&6 = 4. Which sounds weird but it is true because `&` sign is an arithmetic and. This one take 2 binary numbers and `AND` each bits together given the following table:

```
if 0 and 0 => 0
if 0 and 1 => 0
if 1 and 0 => 0
if 1 and 1 => 1
```

5 in binary is represented by 0101

6 in binary is represented by 0110

The arithmetic AND of 5&6 is 0100 (in binary) which is equal to 4 in decimal value.

To answer to your question : If you want to split your array at the arrival on the server, choose some integer that is not part of the ensemble you were addressing: for instance if you know your integers are always less than 10 choose 100:

```
int[] process;
process = new int[]{4, 5, 100, 6, 6, 7};
```

On the server side you just have to split the array given the 'token 100'.

```
int [] a = { 4,5,100,6,6,4 };
int index = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i] == 100) {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}
int [] aBefore = new int[index];
int [] aAfter = new int[a.length-index-1];
System.arraycopy(a, 0, aBefore, 0, index);
System.arraycopy(a, index+1, aAfter, 0, a.length-index-1);
```